# C++ MsgPack unable to compile

Tags: c++, serialization, msgpack

Am getting the following error when i tried to cmompile the code which uses the library

http://msgpack.org/ , i tried the first example in C++ section ( documentation of library )

```
g++ hello.cc -lmsgpack -o hello

/usr/local/lib/libmsgpack.so: undefined reference to `__sync_sub_and_fetch_4'
```

Any help is appreciable ..

g++ version details ..

$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)

Comment: Implementation status: `Currently, no RPC implementation is not available.`  Lovely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc atomic built-in functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786284/gcc-atomic-built-in-functions)

Comment: What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: pls find my edit on g++ version details

Comment: Update your GCC tool-chain. Or try to add `-march=pentium` or `-march=i486`, etc.

Comment: can u pls specify how to add this in configure script..

Comment: try this: `g++ -march=i486 hello.cc -lmsgpack -o hello `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me ...

```
Update your GCC tool-chain. Or try to add -march=pentium or -march=i486, etc.
```

@qehgt Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating your g++ compiler. Such error suggests that your compiler is too old and the code you are trying to compile is too new for it.

I am using g++ version 4.6.3 and there are no problems.