# Atomic Operations in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, atomic

I am trying to port some code I wrote from Mac OS X to Linux and am struggling to find a suitable replacement for the OSX only `OSAtomic.h`. I found the gcc `__sync*` family, but I am not sure it will be compatible with the older compiler/kernel I have. I need the code to run on GCC v4.1.2 and kernel 2.6.18.

The particular operations I need are:

- Increment
- Decrement
- Compare and Swap

What is weird is that running `locate stdatomic.h` on the linux machine finds the header file (in a c++ directory), whereas running the same command on my OSX machine (gcc v4.6.3) returns nothing. What do I have to install to get the stdatomic library, and will it work with gcc v 4.1.2?

As a side note, I can't use any third party libraries.

Comment: The GCC atomic builtins are documented as part of [4.1.1](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

Comment: Similar for increment and fetch and no GCC version requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353371/atomic-increment-fetch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, nothing is there to stop you from using `OSAtomic` operations on other platforms. The sources for `OSAtomic` operations for ARM, x86 and PPC are a part of Apple's libc which is opensource. Just make sure you are not using `OSSpinLock` as that is specific to Mac OS X, but this can be easily replaced by Linux futexes.

See these:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/i386/sys/OSAtomic.s
 http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/ppc/sys/OSAtomic.s
 http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/arm/sys/OSAtomic.s

Alternatively, you can use the `sync_*` family, which I believe should work on most platforms, which I believe are described here: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic

Answer (score 5):

The [OpenPA project](http://trac.mcs.anl.gov/projects/openpa/) provides a portable library of atomic operations under an MIT-style license. This is one I have used before and it is pretty straightforward. The code for your operations would look like

```
#include "opa_primitives.h"

OPA_int_t my_atomic_int = OPA_INT_T_INITIALIZER(0);

/* increment */
OPA_incr_int(&my_atomic_int);

/* decrement */
OPA_decr_int(&my_atomic_int);

/* compare and swap */
old = OPA_cas_int(&my_atomic_int, expected, new);
```

It also contains fine-grained memory barriers (i.e. read, write, and read/write) instead of just a full memory fence.

The [main header file](http://trac.mcs.anl.gov/projects/openpa/browser/trunk/src/opa_primitives.h#L29) has a comment showing the operations that are available in the library.

Answer (score 4):

GCC atomic intrinsics have been available since GCC 4.0.1.

There is nothing stopping you building [GCC 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html) or Clang with GCC 4.1.2 and then getting all the newer features such as [C11 atomics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29).

There are many locations you can find BSD licensed assembler implementations of atomics as a last resort.