# How to use atomic variables in C?

Tags: c, linux, atomic

I need to use an atomic variable in C as this variable is accessed across different threads. Don't want a race condition.

My code is running on CentOS. What are my options?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable Also, this may be worth the read: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-sema.pdf

Comment: Isn't that to prevent certain variables from being compiler-optimzed? I do know about the threads and semaphore way but is there a "cheaper" way like "atomic int myvariable" ?

Comment: Ultimately, "atomic" is up to the hardware and OS, not the compiler.

Comment: It looks like pthreads for CentOS are available, so you could use mutex to synchronize access to things.

Comment: The type `volatile sig_atomic_t` is guaranteed to have atomic access

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner: `volatile` **DOES NOT DO THAT**.  Please refer to the Wikipedia article you linked to: "Operations on volatile variables are not atomic..."

Comment: @DietrichEpp he said IMPLEMENT, so I thought maybe he needed to actually create some kind of threading on his own. Good luck getting out of a spin-wait loop without volatile variables.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I read the sig_atomic_t is actually an integer. Can I actually use this as a global int value like this? voltatile sig_atomic_t variablename   Seems to compile.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner: You can't implement a spin-lock just using `volatile`, because the processor will reorder IO even if the compiler doesn't.  The question also says "don't want a race condition", and `volatile` just isn't the right tool for the job, if you are concerned about race conditions.

Comment: @Ippier actually I am unsure whether that type is guaranteed to be atomic when accessed from multiple threads (originally it was designed to only be guaranteed to not be interrupted by control jumping to a signal handler)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do an atomic increment and fetch in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353371/how-to-do-an-atomic-increment-and-fetch-in-c) || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083694/atomic-operations-in-c-on-linux || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287451/how-to-perform-atomic-operations-on-linux-that-work-on-x86-arm-gcc-and-icc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using GCC on your CentOS platform, then you can use the [`__atomic` built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins).

Of particular interest might be this function:

> — Built-in Function: `bool __atomic_always_lock_free (size_t size, void *ptr)`
>   This built-in function returns true if objects of `size` bytes always generate lock free atomic instructions for the target architecture. `size` must resolve to a compile-time constant and the result also resolves to a compile-time constant.
>
> `ptr` is an optional pointer to the object that may be used to determine alignment. A value of `0` indicates typical alignment should be used. The compiler may also ignore this parameter.
>
> ```
>       if (_atomic_always_lock_free (sizeof (long long), 0))
> ```

Answer (score 24):

**C11 atomic primitives**

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

```
_Atomic const int * p1;  // p is a pointer to an atomic const int
const atomic_int * p2;   // same
const _Atomic(int) * p3; // same
```

Added in glibc 2.28. Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 (glibc 2.27) by compiling glibc from source: [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/52454603#52454603) Later also tested on Ubuntu 20.04, glibc 2.31.

Example adapted from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

atomic_int acnt;
int cnt;

int f(void* thr_data)
{
    (void)thr_data;
    for(int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
        ++cnt;
        ++acnt;
        // for this example, relaxed memory order is sufficient, e.g.
        // atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&acnt, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    thrd_t thr[10];
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_create(&thr[n], f, NULL);
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_join(thr[n], NULL);

    printf("The atomic counter is %u\n", acnt);
    printf("The non-atomic counter is %u\n", cnt);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c -pthread
./main.out
```

Possible output:

```
The atomic counter is 10000
The non-atomic counter is 8644
```

The non-atomic counter is very likely to be smaller than the atomic one due to racy access across threads to the non atomic variable.

Disassembly analysis at: [How do I start threads in plain C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to toss in my two cents in case someone benefits.  Atomic operations are a major problem in Linux.  I used gatomic.h at one time only to find it gone.  I see all kinds of different atomic options of either questionable reliability or availability -- and I see things changing all the time.  They can be complex with tests needed by O/S level, processor, whatever.  You can use a mutex -- not only complex by dreadfully slow.

Although perhaps not ideal in threads, this works great for atomic operations on shared memory variables.  It is simple and it works on every O/S and processor and configuration known to man (or woman), dead reliable, easy to code, and will always work.

Any code can me made atomic with a simple primitive -- a semaphore.  It is something that is true/false, 1/0, yes/no, locked/unlocked -- binary.

Once you establish the semaphore:

```
set semaphore   //must be atomic
```

do all the code you like which will be atomic as the semaphore will block for you

```
release semaphore  //must be atomic
```

Relatively straight forward except the "must be atomic" lines.

It turns out that you easily assign your semaphores a number (I use a define so they have a name like "#define OPEN_SEM 1" and "#define "CLASS_SEM 2" and so forth.

Find out your largest number and when your program initializes open a file in some directory (I use one just for this purpose).  If not there create it:

```
if (ablockfd < 0) {         //ablockfd is static in case you want to 
                            //call it over and over           
    char *get_sy_path();                
    char lockname[100];                 

    strcpy(lockname, get_sy_path());    
    strcat(lockname, "/metlock");       
    ablockfd = open(lockname, O_RDWR);
    //error code if ablockfd bad
}
```

Now to gain a semaphore:

Now use your semaphore number to "lock" a "record" in your file of length one byte.  Note -- the file will never actually occupy disk space and no disk operation occurs.

```
//sem_id is passed in and is set from OPEN_SEM or CLASS_SEM or whatever you call your semaphores.

lseek(ablockfd, sem_id, SEEK_SET); //seeks to the bytes in file of 
                                   //your semaphore number
result = lockf(ablockfd, F_LOCK, 1);   

if (result != -1) {                    
   //got the semaphore
} else {
    //failed
}
```

To test if the semaphore is held:

```
result = lockf(ablockfd, F_TEST, 1);  //after same lseek
```

To release the semaphore:

```
result = lockf(ablockfd, F_ULOCK, 1);   //after same lseek
```

And all the other things you can do with lockf -- blocking/non-blocking, etc.

Note -- this is WAY faster than a mutex, it goes away if the process dies (a good thing), simple to code, and I know of no operating system with any processor with any number of them or number of cores that cannot atomically lock a record ... so simple code that just works.  The file never really exists (no bytes but in directory), seems to be no practical limit to how many you may have.  I have used this for years on machines with no easy atomic solutions.