# Number of threads waiting for semaphore

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

So my problem is simple, I need to know how many threads are waiting for the semaphore(are queued). Initially I thought `sem_getvalue` would return a negative number showing the number of threads blocked by the semaphore but it only goes down to 0 and stays there. I also tried to declare a global variable like `int waiting` and incrementing it before calling `sem_wait` with `waiting++` and decrementing it after the call but it seems like this solution is not working(by which I am baffled because I thought incrementing and decrementing won't cause race condition). I have looked at the `semaphore.h` but none of the functions seem to do what I want.
Writing here, I came up with an imperfect solution of declaring a second semaphore and initializing it with 0 then calling `sem_post` on it before the actual `sem_wait` and a wait after the actual wait. Haven't tested whether it works but even if it does it seems a little hacky a not very nice!

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_getvalue.html according to the doc it does exactly what you want. Maybe post your code?

Comment: Unfortunately: POSIX.1 permits two possibilities for the value returned in sval: either 0 is returned; or a negative number whose absolute value is the count of the number of processes and threads currently blocked in sem_wait(3).  Linux adopts the former behavior.

Comment: Increment/decrement is a read-calculate-write-operation, so it is not thread-safe. If you protect the `waiting` counter with a dedicated mutex, then that should work.

Comment: C doesn't guarantee there won't be any race conditions even with simple increment/decrement in one thread and reads in another - unless the variables involved are `_Atomic`.

Comment: There is something wrong with your design if you attempt this for any reason other than, maybe, debugging.  I have written a lot of multithreaded apps and have never found a need to monitor a semaphore count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into why you have a lot of threads waiting on a semaphore, one way to solve this is what you already have tried, having a counter.
This counter has to be `*atomic*`, or do something like:

```
pthread_mutex_t wait_m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int wait_counter = 0;

void inc_wait_counter() 
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&wait_m);
    wait_counter ++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&wait_m);

}

void dec_wait_counter() 
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&wait_m);
    wait_counter --;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&wait_m);

}

int get_wait_counter()
{
    /* No need to lock here for only reading wait_counter */
    return wait_counter;
}
```

Then just something like:

```
inc_wait_counter();
sem_wait(...);
dec_wait_counter();
```

NOTE: Using atomic integers instead, I suggest to check: [How to do an atomic increment and fetch in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353371/how-to-do-an-atomic-increment-and-fetch-in-c)

Comment: In many cases, `get_wait_counter()` will be ok without a lock, but it cannot be guaranteed that writing an integer is an atomic operation (e.g. on an 8-bit processor which nowadays is still found in some embedded systems). So unless integer write (also considering the alignment of the `wait_counter` variable) is known to be atomic on the given system, a lock should be used also for read.