# In C using Clang atomics, how should I perform an atomic pre-increment?

Tags: c, clang, atomic

Expanding from this question ([How to do an atomic increment and fetch in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353371/how-to-do-an-atomic-increment-and-fetch-in-c))

In C, using Clang compiler, how can I do the atomic equivalent of

`const int v = ++x`

As I understand it, `v = atomic_fetch_add(&x, 1)` will return the original value (ie `v = x++`), which is a post-increment.

How do I return the updated value of x instead?

Note: this question is about C, and any replies with "use std::atomic<>" will be downvoted accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```c
v = atomic_fetch_add(&x, 1) + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `clang`/`gcc` intrinsic function `__atomic_add_fetch()`, which first adds to a number then returns the new value (There's also `__atomic_fetch_add()` which acts like the C11 `atomic_fetch_add()`):

```c
int x = 1;
const int v = __atomic_add_fetch(&x, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST); // v is 2
```

Comment: These instrinsics exist - both pre and post forms - for add, sub, and bitwise and, xor, or, nand operations.

Comment: My goodness, I need more coffee this morning, I didn't see the pre forms.

Answer (score 2):

For `_Atomic int x;`, your example `local = ++shared;` already does work atomically, like [GNU C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) `__atomic_add_fetch` (not `..._fetch_add`).  ISO C11 is no different for this than ISO C++.

The downside is that you can't specify a memory-order weaker than seq_cst, and there's no equivalent for other operators, unlike GNU C `__atomic_or_fetch`.

Compilers are generally decent at optimising ISO C `atomic_fetch_add(&x, 1) + 1`, although it wasn't until GCC12 that GCC managed to make the same asm for this as for using the return value of `++x`.  Before that, on LL/SC machines (like ARM, and AArch64 before ARMv8.1), it would do `fetch_add` but then not using the incremented value it had in a register, doing a separate `add` after the loop on the load result.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyagA%2BudTkVjVEQJDqzTAGF09AK5smBpwBkCTNgAcp4ARtikUlrkAA7oSsT2TK4eXgZxCXZC/oEhbOGRPNHW2LZJIkQspEQpnt48Vtg2WUwVVUQ5wWERUVaV1bVpDUr9HQFd%2BT1FAJRW6O6kqJxcAKQATADMAageOADUKxvOI5gsJGwEqAB0SIe4K1oAgg%2BPAUR726ak2EQLTKaBADuEFMj3Olw%2Bwj2ACoYtMVgB2ABCLz2aL231%2BpCYBzWKLxsMOKKeiIAIi8Xm9Iagvj8/gDsIC1iCwegLqhIe9YfDkaj0Zi/nszmzLqYaD9UEhTCxMJgIDFyHseNNcUilUSKQjyU8uLN6NwAKz8bxcHTkdDcZx7JTzRbYXEbPjkIjaXWzADWIA20iuAA4AJxrABsPB4Qd9G190l9vsM3Gk/DYIAN0RNZotXH4ShA0Rdpt15DgsBQGDYMQYEUo1FL5cYkXEpDYoY20To9CIEWzEFCrvIoQCVQAntwnaWOMIAPJMejD/PkHBsYzASRzwjfMoAN2w2bn2HUpXcHZH/DeTV79AIoVIQ9cOF7RFIBCTvALNCMwCUADUCIyJzFmMecjCGIEicDIQGKCoGi9voshGCYIDmKYlgXqE2aQLM6AxC0O4ALQThsey4WwqAxO4hykhg1R7rhLAGhsWZNKULSOEwLhuHUIBrGs5B%2BOMeQFFICKxPEiRCIM3jcSJmRJJ0AlTMJJRlEIbQDBxaRSUpLSqWMuTdIUimjBJXE8SM7RyfpQmzDaCxLAYD7YMsfB6oaxq9hmjwAEoALJ7MAqAcqGVyERAF5MO46gqhAziKvgxBkA6DR7K4ZYVqQDrSNM/B5jo0wuVwCbkEmKbkGm/AZlmObOq6eXkJ63p%2BoGIZhhGUYxnGXAMaV7ncNlNWFogRbIGgbK1pWVAQDWaVoMAPBrA0bYdqQXY9nO/asKQs6jmy45EFOM69guS4rmaa7MQQW47mae4HkeL6UMIZ5zqh16bbeyxmg%2BT7HrMb4sB%2B36/v%2BJpOoIwHiJI4Fg5BaiaHO%2Bg8fBZgWIYl7oRAmHYUkeEEYxzRJKx7GpPUvFsRZkyFNJYnJOpJMZNT5OCcMTHKa0Rm0wYWnlKMjNTH07TGcMPP8ZZypzLZYHOt8TkFvqXBGt1c4ZuovpBrhQbSH5AVKmsVw8Hs0WxYQJDpesjqKilY2m5saxZdV%2Ba1Ug2Ayj0GN1V6PBXAiCLSFoBrSP6vprL6PAIr6CIbB1hXFamPWZlYVU5QWQ0QCWo1pVWk3p3WaBVE282tgwS0rb261DoBY7MHt06zqd2CLiYJ38Gdm7br2N2oIeMsPR2ctmi9N5YB92WPs%2BzkCO%2BX4/oCf4Afd0MgZDsjQ8osMwV6hhLohKOoejmM4dw%2BGEcRpHkRslFkB26i0fRePnQ4EBOILpOYLzlP0y0z8f7JIsU5zLPaXZsTf%2B%2BMVLCz0n/IWAsOZQOqG/KQ1lbR2QaA5GW%2BUFZlXNNwLyvl/KBV1vrUKAQIpRRinsOKJtEoW2zhEB0Gw7ZJ0ds7HAkQ3Zy2jsmWOSteoJ1zDVD0HsvY%2Bz9gHIOIcw4Rw6l1TBFV7a5QGvAVOI1Up1kzlNHOecNy%2BlwgFJGoYtALSLp2agq0zRl02hXHaVd9q12bvXY6w95wEHXHYS67d9ydzuk6U8fd%2BADzekPe8o8foT3%2BlPIGc9QbyEXmBZe8hV7QXhgYJG29kKozQvAfe2ND640aKA7wj82LPz4hApmVNP4wPKT/UpfMuZgOgcA5m%2BSdLwNgTUSpZk4G/yZogiW9lpYhLlhguOmjtEsD2DsJcSpPZaD1gbMhFCEpmySpbNKiUGH8PdhsDYwVtl7P2fsqObluHx2zHwh2%2BU1iJiiFw9MPDGGzC3MtAm0ggA))

Comment: Avoiding `tmp = ++shared` makes sense  if you want to use a memory order weaker than `seq_cst`, though.  Then you need to use `atomic_fetch_add_explicit(...) + 1`, or GNU C `__atomic_add_fetch`.