# Error while compiling Mono Source Tree on CentOS - 6.X

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, mono, centos

I want to install a latest Mono version on my CentOS (i686). As there is no ready to use binary distribution I tried to pull the latest Mono Source 3.2.3 from [here](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/). After pulling the source, I extracted it, change directory to it and tried below sequence of commands -

```
[root@localhost mono-3.2.3]# ./configure
```

No problems reported

```
[root@localhost mono-3.2.3]# make
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata'
  CCLD     pedump
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-assembly.o): In function `InterlockedDecrement':
/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata/../../mono/utils/atomic.h:66: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-assembly.o): In function `InterlockedIncrement':
/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata/../../mono/utils/atomic.h:61: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-cominterop.o): In function `InterlockedDecrement':
/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata/../../mono/utils/atomic.h:66: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-cominterop.o): In function `InterlockedIncrement':
/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata/../../mono/utils/atomic.h:61: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-cominterop.o): In function `InterlockedDecrement':
/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata/../../mono/utils/atomic.h:66: undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-image.o):/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata/../../mono/utils/atomic.h:61: more undefined references to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4' follow
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-marshal.o): In function `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer':
/usr/local/src/mono-3.2.3/mono/metadata/../../mono/utils/atomic.h:56: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(libmonoruntime_la-marshal.o): In function `InterlockedExchangePointer':
```

While trying to resolve this I found [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130740/link-error-when-compiling-gcc-atomic-operation-in-32-bit-mode) and [this](http://www.eschrade.com/page/undefined-reference-to-__sync_add_and_fetch_4/). I tried to implement the solution mentioned there but had no luck.
Has anybody faced this?

Regards,
Omky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added two compiler switches in make file.

CPPFLAGS = -m32 -march=i686

This worked for me.