# Why std::atom::is_lock_free doesn't compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Just a bit code of C++11:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<atomic>

struct A { int a[4]; };
struct B { int x, y; };
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
            << std::atomic<A>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n'
            << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
            << std::atomic<B>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n';
}
```

Compile with mac+clang, it gives error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___atomic_is_lock_free", referenced from:
    _main in atomics.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

clang + ubuntu docker gives:

```
root@b01946bedcf2:/# clang++ --version
clang version 4.0.0-1ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_400/rc1)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
root@b01946bedcf2:/# clang++ 1.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread
/tmp/1-7cc6e9.o: In function `std::atomic<A>::is_lock_free() const':
1.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6atomicI1AE12is_lock_freeEv[_ZNKSt6atomicI1AE12is_lock_freeEv]+0x1b): undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
/tmp/1-7cc6e9.o: In function `std::atomic<B>::is_lock_free() const':
1.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6atomicI1BE12is_lock_freeEv[_ZNKSt6atomicI1BE12is_lock_freeEv]+0x1b): undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And on RHEL7+gcc4.8.5, it gives:

```
$g++ 1.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread && ./a.out
/tmp/ccW9pNc2.o: In function `std::atomic<A>::is_lock_free() const':
1.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6atomicI1AE12is_lock_freeEv[_ZNKSt6atomicI1AE12is_lock_freeEv]+0x17): undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is really odd. What's wrong with the code, or does it require a super-high version of compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link error when compiling gcc atomic operation in 32-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130740/link-error-when-compiling-gcc-atomic-operation-in-32-bit-mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the [atomic library](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/LIbrary).

```
$ g++ 1.cpp -std=c++11 -latomic && ./a.out
```

Comment: Yes, -latomic works for gcc version higher than 4.9.2.